# GWT 2.X No resource found for key

Tags: compiler-construction, gwt

I've developed a GWT app using i18n internationalization. In Host/Dev mode it works fine, but launching GWT compile gives this error: No resource found for key xxx, like below.

```
Compiling module ...rte.RTE
   Scanning for additional dependencies: file:/home/.../client/i18n/RTEValidationMessages.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for '...client.i18n.RTEMessages'
         Rebinding ...client.i18n.RTEMessages
            Invoking com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext@e7dfd0
               Processing interface ...client.i18n.RTEMessages
                  Generating method body for txtIndirizzo3()
                     [ERROR] No resource found for key 'txtIndirizzo3'
```

Messages are loaded with late binding.

```
public class RTEValidationMessages {
    private RTEMessages additionalMessages; 

    public RTEValidationMessages() {
        additionalMessages = GWT.create(RTEMessages.class);
    }
}
```

Deleting the method which gives the error, results in another random method with error, say not the method before or after in the interface ...client.i18n.RTEMessages.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar error once when using internationalization. I had properties files for English and Polish languages: `labels_en.properties` and `labels_pl.properties`. The solution was to create also a file `labels.properties` (in my case it was just a copy of `labels_en.properties`). It is weird but somehow it helped.

You should also keep your properties files in the same package as your `RTEMessages` class.

Comment: Thanks. Google should have made their Showcase project more modular. Using code snippets from it is extremely inconvenient because of dependencies like this one.

Comment: GWT uses this file as a default, when the key is not found in specific locale file. As alternative you can annotate your methods in interface with `@DefaultMessage`

Answer (score 1):

also 2 important things (see [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n.html#DevGuideAnnotations)):

> In order to use internationalized
>   characters, make sure that your host
>   HTML file contains the charset=utf8
>   content type in the meta tag in the
>   header:
>
> ```
> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
> ```
>
> You must also ensure that all relevant
>   source and .properties files are set
>   to be in the UTF-8 charset in your
>   IDE.