# Problem using GWT-VL?

Tags: java, validation, gwt

I'm trying to evaluate GWT validation library with a very simple example taken from the author site.
and here is a code snippet

```
validator.addValidators( "birthYear",new IntegerValidator(schoolName_txt, 1890, 2009)
                .addActionForFailure(new StyleAction("validationFailedBorder"))
                .addActionForFailure(new LabelTextAction(error_label))
                );
```

but the problem is that when I run the application I got the following error:

```
no property localization given for key: birthYear
```

but I'm sure that I have included this key in my localization files,so what is this?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be the same problem as solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015734/gwt-2-x-no-resource-found-for-key?

Comment: Ever get this?  I'm seeing similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get rid of this error message you have to extend ValidationMessages:**

```
import eu.maydu.gwt.validation.client.i18n.ValidationMessages;
public class CustomValidationMessages extends ValidationMessages {
  @Override
  public String getPropertyName(String propertyName) {
    return propertyName;   // This just returns the property name instead of the error message
  }
}
```

**Then change pass an instance of this class to the ValidationProcessor instance instead of just an empty parameter:**

```
ValidationProcessor validator = new DefaultValidationProcessor(new CustomValidationMessages());
```

**The purpose of this I suppose to give you a chance to change the displayed input name in the error message if your app is multi-language.**