# GWT Constants is not working - Searched the following resources: (blank)

Tags: gwt

I have a package - client.ui.desktop.event

in this package I have a class EventReadViewDesktopImpl which has the following code in it:

```
public static interface EventReadConstants extends Constants {

  String activitiesDataGridEmptyLabel();

  String activitiesDataGridNameColumn();

  String activitiesDataGridTimeColumn();
}
```

In the same package I have a properties file EventReadConstants.properties which has the following properties in it:

```
activitiesDataGridEmptyLabel = Empty
activitiesDataGridNameColumn = Name
activitiesDataGridTimeColumn = Time
```

This is the first time I have used GWT Constants - I'm not trying to do internationalization yet I just want to have my Strings externalized.

Now, everytime I run the project I get the OnModuleLoad exception No Resource Found For Key 'activitiesDataGridNameColumn'

What I find weird is that the line immediately under that says "Searched the following resources:" with nothing following it.

[GWT 2.X No resource found for key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015734/gwt-2-x-no-resource-found-for-key)

After reading through this I made sure that the charsets for everything was set to utf-8 and my html file had the utf-8 flag in it.  Can anybody help me figure out what is happening here, as of right now I am completely lost as how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Show the code where you use/access the constant.

Comment: Provide the code where you access the constant. Problem lies there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the interface is an inner class (err, inner interface), it could be that GWT is looking for `EventReadViewDesktopImpl.EventReadConstants.properties` instead. Try moving the interface to its own file, or renaming the properties file.

Comment: I wonder if that wouldn't rather be `EventReadViewDesktopImpl$EventReadConstants.properties` (notice the `$` instead of `.`)

Comment: That was exactly the problem - I feel stupid - I moved out the interface instead of renaming the properties - thanks a lot